# classifying pairs of idempotent matrices

Tags: rt.representation-theory

though classifying pairs of matrices up to simultaneous conjugation is known to be wild, it seems to me a folklore that classifying pairs of idempotent matrices (up to simultaneous conjugation) is possible -- or in other words, tame. However I could not find a proper reference for this. Putting it differently, I would like to know a classification of the indecomposable modules of $k\langle x, y\rangle/(x^2-x,y^2-y)$.

My motivation is to understand the paper of W. W. Crawley-Boevey with the title Functorial filtrations III: Semidihedral algebras, where this is used implicitly.

I understand that this must be common knowledge for experts in representation theory of associative algebras, but I tried and could not find a reference.

Thank you, and regards,
Jimmy

Comment: If the characteristic is not 2, then A is an idempotent iff I-2A is an involution. So you are essentially looking at the representation type of the infinite dihedral group.  Quick googling of representation type infinite dihedral group  gave me a chapter of a book by Benson giving all indecomposables from which you can deduce tame

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Thank you for the reference. Yes that solves the case for fields with characteristic not 2. However I am actually interested in the characteristic 2 case -- in particular the GF(2). What can we say about this case? Thanks.

Comment: So you want to characterize $k$-vector spaces with two projections. A projection is characterized by its image and its kernel, which have to be complementary subspaces. So a solution will follow from the solution to the four-subspaces problem (e.g., http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379504002575 ) after throwing away the indecomposables where the appropriate pairs of subspaces are not complementary. Or am I off here?

Comment: @darijgrinberg I thought so yesterday, but was not sure whether this correspondence is correct. Now I verified it and I think you are right. Thank you! I will go ahead to read about the 4-subspace problem.

Comment: @darijgrinberg And the $4$-subspace problem itself is a subproblem of classifying representations of the $\tilde{D}_4$ quiver, with all arrows directed inward. (Namely, the subproblem where the maps associated to the $4$ arrows are injective.) $\tilde{D}_4$ is affine, so this is a tame problem.

Comment: In general, classifying pairs of nilpotent matrices is a wild problem. Even classifying pairs of commuting nilpotent matrices or very much restricted kinds of pairs. You can take a look at V. Ginzburg's paper "Principal Nilpotent pairs in a semisimple Lie algebra, I" http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9903059 Section 5 for an example of wildness.